# Can LiFePO4 BMSes be connected in parallel without causing charge/discharge issues?

Tags: lifepo4, bms

I have two LiFePO4 battery packs in 4S configuration: one with 2x4 cells (4S2P) and one with 3x4 (4S3P) cells. Each pack has a 4S BMS.

Are there any potential issues with connecting those two in parallel at the BMS charge/discharge side?

As the batteries drop in voltage when discharging, will there be a lot of losses in 'cross feed' between the two packs, where one will charge the other?

Comment: I would expect that there is enough resistance in the BMS to act as balancing resistors. So losses wouldn't be in the cross-feed charging each other as much as current passing through the balancing resistance on the way out to the load.

Comment: When first connecting them, put a resistor (like 1 ohm) between them and measure the voltage across it. When that approaches 0, it'll be safe to connect them.

Comment: Thanks for both comments/answers. There wasn't any huge spark when first connecting them, so I think they were fairly well in balance. Part of my worry is more of a long-term thing: if the batteries in each pack age/deteriorate at different rates and that leads to different charge/discharge patterns, I wonder if I will end up having one pack draining the other or if the BMSes will take care of that in a good way..?